# Run chrome as different user using Selenium and C#

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

As part of a testing project, I am trying to run a chrome instance as different user ('UserA') using Selenium and C#. I have tried all suggestions I could find, but nothing works. No matter what I do, the Chrome instance that is opened during the test, runs as the user logged into the machine and not as 'UserA'. Everything runs locally.

I am fairly new to this, so any advice/suggestion is appreciated

Comment: did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46342017/c-sharp-selenium-start-chrome-with-different-user-profile

Comment: I have tried the suggestion and I can see that the chrome loads the right profile (the one for 'UserA'). However, if I check the running processes, I can see that the same Chrome instance is set to be running as the user logged into the machine, not user 'UserA'. Looks like by only loading a different profile, does not make the browser run as that user

Comment: First make .exe of your written test then Log out and Log in as another User then try to execute this exe